# Python [distinction between re-reference and mutation in function]

Tags: python, global-variables, mutation

I have been struggling so see how these two blocks of code do no yield the same output of K (Mutates K such that it contains all of the strings, s, originally in K such that f(s) returns True, and no other elements)

```
def f(s):
    return 'a' in s
K = ['a','b','a','c']
def satisfiesF(L):
ansList = []
for char in L:
    if f(char) == True:
        ansList += [char,]  
L = ansList
return len(L)
```

and

```
def f(s):
    return 'a' in s
K = ['a','b','a','c']
def satisfiesF(L):
    ansList = []
    for char in L:
        if f(char) == True:
            ansList += [char,]    
    CloneL = L[:]
    for e in CloneL:
        if e not in ansList:
            L.remove(e)
    return len(L)
```

When I type print K the first block gives:

```
['a','b','a','c']
```

while the second block gives:

```
['a','a']
```

which is what I want. However I am trying to understand the mechanism in which it yields such answers. To me it is saying that I can mutate/change the input of the function but I cannot just reassign my input to what I want.

Comment: Who wrote this? `ansList += [char,]` would be written `ansList.append(char)` by anyone sane. See also `if f(char) == True` vs. just `if f(char):`. And I'm not sure what your confusion is: the first version adds items that *do* match **to a new list** whereas the second removes items that *don't* match **from the old one**.